# Jade: ReferenceError: TokContext is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I make my `app.js` simplest node server. To do that I installed next libs: 
`npm install node-jsx react express jade`.

Now when I start it with `node app.js` it gets the next error:

```
c:\Programming\React_Examples\server rendering\node_modules\jade\node_modules\constantinople\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:2275
  _classCallCheck(this, TokContext);
                        ^
ReferenceError: TokContext is not defined
    at new TokContext (c:\Programming\React_Examples\server rendering\node_modules\jade\node_modules\constantinople\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:2275:25)
    at Object../state (c:\Programming\React_Examples\server rendering\node_modules\jade\node_modules\constantinople\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:2285:11)
    at s (c:\Programming\React_Examples\server rendering\node_modules\jade\node_modules\constantinople\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1:681)
    at c:\Programming\React_Examples\server rendering\node_modules\jade\node_modules\constantinople\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1:732
    at Object../expression (c:\Programming\React_Examples\server rendering\node_modules\jade\node_modules\constantinople\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:907:21)
    at s (c:\Programming\React_Examples\server rendering\node_modules\jade\node_modules\constantinople\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1:681)
    at e (c:\Programming\React_Examples\server rendering\node_modules\jade\node_modules\constantinople\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1:852)
    at c:\Programming\React_Examples\server rendering\node_modules\jade\node_modules\constantinople\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1:870
    at a (c:\Programming\React_Examples\server rendering\node_modules\jade\node_modules\constantinople\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1:150)
    at Object.<anonymous> (c:\Programming\React_Examples\server rendering\node_modules\jade\node_modules\constantinople\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1:383)
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is a conflict between the node-jsx and acorn modules (the latter used by Jade).

If you can save all your JSX in files whose extension is something other than .js, say .jsx, you could replace your

```
require('node-jsx').install();
```

call with:

```
require('node-jsx').install({extension: '.jsx'});
```

Another alternative might be a different templating engine from Jade.

Or limiting your JSX includes to modules outside of your main one (not sure about this one, but worth trying if necessary).

See https://github.com/pugjs/jade/issues/1925